# How to see the symbol visibility on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, symbols

I'm running into "visibility different" link warning, but can't fix it even with -fvisibility=hidden set on both size libraries. So I'd like to examine the library to see whether or not the visiblity is set right.

But nm on Mac doesn't show vibility. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks